# Debugging with XDebug PHPStorm and SoapUUI

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xdebug, soapui, phpstorm

I've switched from Eclipse to PHPStorm and everything is working fine but only the debugging with XDebug ans SoapUI is still not working.

XDebug is installed. I used to add a GET parameter `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP` on the end of the wsdl url in SoapUI and Eclipse stopped at the first breakpoint properly.

When I close Eclipse, start PHPStorm and click to start listening for debug connections nothing happens.

I use `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM_DBGP`. Only a Chrome-Plugin is able to start debugging in PHPStorm, but I need to debug with SoapUI too.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Well you can always try to configure xdebug to attempt to establish debug session on **each** run (you will see around 1 sec delay in case when it fails to establish connection, e.g. when PhpStorm is not listening) -- `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`. Other than that -- collect xdebug logs http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log  and provide your xdebug configuration (from php.ini as well as from `phpinfo()` output)

Comment: OK, I got it. I had to set path settings at PHP Servers configuration.
It works now! ;)

Comment: For the benefit of others, you are able to answer your own question and accept your own answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set path settings at PHP Servers configuration.